# Determining weight matrix

Tags: neural-network

I need to design a neural network which has the following behavior:

```
p(1)={0,1,1,1} outputs a(1)={0,1,0,0}
p(2)={1,1,0,1} outputs a(2)={0,0,1,0}
p(3)={0,0,1,0} outputs a(3)={0,0,0,1}
p(4)={0,0,1,1} outputs a(4)={1,1,0,1}
```

How can i do so? Which type of neural network should I use? Which learning method can be used here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it seems as though you could use a simple feedforward neural network with one input layer one, one hidden layer and one output layer. You can use your training data to train the neural network using the backpropogation algorithm.

See this page for more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

Comment: Ok that was exactly the type of answer I wanted. There are so many different types that I got totally confused. Can you suggest a subjective book having lot of examples on neural networks and its types and design?

Comment: What's your level of mathematical experience? Knowing this will help me make a suggestion. In any case Bishop's book http://www.amazon.com/Neural-Networks-Pattern-Recognition-Christopher/dp/0198538642 is a classic.